# Assessing accuracy of image classification using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, image, accuracy

I have classified images in ArcGIS Desktop with the support vector machine classifier, and am now struggling with the accuracy assessment. I have only been able to find tutorials on how to do it manually by creating points manually and calculating the kappa index with excel... but I cannot find any detailed steps on how to 'create accuracy assessment points' or 'compute confusion matrix' through ArcGIS, (under spatial analyst tools).

Any pointers?

Comment: Please take the community tour here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour and edit your question to only ask one question.

Comment: To clarify: Are you wanting to run the accuracy assessment from within the ArcMap / ESRI Geoprocessing Tools?

Comment: Yes, that would be preferable.

Comment: Question has been closed...but as a guide...You need to create the Accuracy Assessment Points. Use the classified image as the input and choose "Classified" as the Target Field. Once its run, choose the "Update Accuracy". Use a digitised polygon of known classes, Ground-Truth as the target field. Run it. Then use that in the confusion matrix.